# Using TOP, Limit while fetching data using ID from database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I read somewhere on Internet that using `TOP`(MSSQL) or `LIMIT`(MySQL) in your query is best practice.

**He explained**: If database has millions record and if you use limit then database algorithm will stop filtering other data when it gets record you requested in `LIMIT` or `TOP`.

My question is when you fetch record using `WHERE` condition with `ID`, So `LIMIT` or `TOP` does make any difference as there'll be unique id in database.

> PK is applied on that column

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TABLE_MASTER 
WHERE ID = 10`
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_MASTER 
WHERE ID = 10 LIMIT 1`
```

If this question already asked Please give me link as I was unable to find stackoverflow thread.

Comment: You get exactly how many rows satisfy a query: no more and no less. For instance, let's say there is an order with 135 order detail items. You don't limit it to 10 if you want the whole order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a WHERE clause picking a specific row by a unique id, then the query is already restricted. It will scan only the single row matching the specific value. There is no benefit to using `TOP` or `LIMIT` in this case.

If someone says to you, "feature X is best practice" that doesn't mean you should use feature X even when it makes no difference.

Using `TOP` or `LIMIT` is useful if you have no condition in the WHERE clause, or a condition that would match a very large number of rows. Instead of returning thousands (or even millions) of rows you don't need, you can restrict the quantity of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance that ID is not unique there is the possibility that more than one record could be found, having no LIMIT or TOP statement could mess up your code if you only expect one record. As such, it usually doesn't hurt to put the LIMIT / TOP statement in there just in case. If the ID is already a unique PK it won't make any difference on an efficiently coded  database engine (aka pretty much all of them).